# Force width menu items horizontal list (CSS)

Tags: css

How can I force all items in a horizontal list (menu) to be the same width?

This is my CSS code so far:

```
a { text-decoration:none; }
#navlist ul { margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none; }
#navlist ul li { display:inline; }
#navlist li a {
  padding:10px;
  margin:2px;
  background:grey;
  color:white;
}
#navlist li a:hover {
  color:white;
  background:black;
}
```

EDIT:

It now works (thanks to @Gaby) by changing the first 3 lines into:

```
#navlist ul { margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none; }
#navlist ul li { float:left; text-align:center; }
#navlist ul li a { text-decoration:none; display:block; width:120px; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

float the elements and make them `block` instead of `inline`

```
#navlist ul { margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none; overflow:auto; }
#navlist ul li { display:block;width:100px;float:left; }
```

You might want to make the `a` to be `block` as well, to fill the `li` and make it all clickable..

Comment: It does not work for me (testing with IE8), but your <a> selector remark gave me a clue. Now it works, see my addition to the questin above

Comment: Yes, but that's because of the `display:block` for `#navlist li a`. I didn't add that at the first try